# Error processing SSAS cube Semaphore timeout

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssas

While doing a process update on a cube I am getting the below error .

OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Communication link failure; 08S01; TCP Provider: The semaphore timeout period has expired.
; 08S01.

Note:Cube size is relatively large.

What is the root cause of this issue

Comment: Please mark the answer as an accepted if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure about SSAS project the timeout value is set to 0 in data source connection string.
Then, The problem is the default value of the ExternalCommandTimeout server property.

You can change that, if you are a server admin, using the following steps:

- connect, using SQL Management Studio, to the Analysis Services server
- right-click on server name, select Properties
- Select Show Advanced (All) Properties on the bottom of the dialogue
- find the ExternalCommandTimeout property and change its value

Comment: Thanks for reply but , external timeout already set to 100 times more than default value 360000 instead of 3600.Data source timeout property set to 00::00::00::0000 as well.Cube is failing after 24 hours of processing

Comment: Some times I get timeout error for SSIS or SSAS because of Boost Priority on the Server. So it's not a bad idea to check it: Boost Priority should be disabled